# How to use JQuery plugin on nuxtjs.

Tags: jquery, vuejs2, nuxt.js

I want to use JQuery plugin rwdImageMaps.

https://github.com/stowball/jQuery-rwdImageMaps

I configured nuxt.config.js

build config

```
vendor: ['jquery'],
plugins: [
  new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
    $: 'jquery',
    jQuery: 'jquery',
    'window.jQuery': 'jquery'
  })
]
```

}

plugin config

```
  plugins: [
    { src: '~/plugins/jquery.rwdImageMaps.min.js', ssr: false }
  ],
```

but Error occurred  in compile phase

11:783  error  'jQuery' is not defined

how to set up nuxt.js for using JQuery plugin that is not uploaded in npm repository.

Answer (score -1):

I changed jquery.rwdImageMaps.min.js to jquery.rwdImageMaps.js .
and added code top of jquery.rwdImageMaps.js

```
import $ from 'jquery'
import jQuery from 'jquery'
```

and successfully executed in chrome.
but in safari error occurred below

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
http://localhost:3000/_nuxt/lib.esm.js.map